# How to get the label value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dynamic tr/td based on json data using below code.

```js
for (i = 0; i < dataPoolJSON.length; i++) {

  html += "<tr id ='row" + i + "' value ='" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "'><td><div class='group'><label id='label" + i + "' for='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' class='ch-control'>";
  html += "<input id='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' type='radio' class='iradio_minimal' value='" + i + "' name='msisdnSelected'/>" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn;
  html += "</label></div></td><td class='hidden-xs'><a id='viewUsage" + i + "' class='viewUsage' onclick='viewDataPoolUsage(this," + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + ");return false;' href=''>View Usage</a>";
  html += "<div class='pool-usage hidden'></div></td>";
  html += "<td><span id='dataAllowed" + i + "'><select>";

  if (dataPoolJSON[i].userSetting != null) {
    html += "<option selected='selected' value='" + dataPoolJSON[i].userSetting.alertPercentageData1 + "'>" + dataPoolJSON[i].userSetting.alertPercentageData1 + "</option>";
  }
  html += "</select></span></td></tr>";
}
$('#data-pool tbody').html(html);
```

Now on click on radio button i need to fetch the msisdn value and current option selected value as but it is not giving me required answer. I am getting the current option selected value but not the msisdn.

```
function submitNewDataUsagealerts() {

    var jsonSubmitData = [];
    var selectedData = document.getElementsByName("msisdnSelected");
    var i = selectedData.length-1;
    for ( j=0; j <= i; j++ ) {

        if(selectedData[j].checked) {

            var valueCurrent = $('#dataAllowed'+selectedData[j].value).find('option:selected').val();
            var row = $('#label'+selectedData[j].value).val();
            item = {}
            item [0] = valueCurrent;
            item [1] = selectedData[j].value;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var msg = document.getElementById('lbltxt').innerHTML;
alert(msg);
```

```html
<label id="lbltxt" style="display:none">Test</label>
```

Comment: as suggested i am trying with var el = document.getElementById('#label'+selectedData[j].value);alert(el.textContent)  but it is giving me error as el is coming as null

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code**

```
 <label id="mylabel" />
```

**JS Code**

```
var lavelValue = $("#mylabel").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the "value" from a label, use `.text()` rather than `.val()`.

```
var row = $('#label'+selectedData[j].value).text();
```

As your label includes an input and the required text, you can put the text inside a container so that it can be referenced without including the input:

The label code is currently (irrelevant code removed) :

```
html += "<label id='label" + i + "' for='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' class='ch-control'>";
html += "<input id='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' type='radio' class='iradio_minimal' value='" + i + "' name='msisdnSelected'/>";
html += dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn;
html += "</label>";
```

change this to:

```
html += "<label id='label" + i + "' for='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' class='ch-control'>";
html += "<input id='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' type='radio' class='iradio_minimal' value='" + i + "' name='msisdnSelected'/>" ;
html += "<span>" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "</span>";
html += "</label>";
```

Then your selector can be:

```
var row = $('#label'+selectedData[j].value + ">span").text();
```

---

Alternatively, move the input out of the label as you're already using `label for=`:

```
html += "<input id='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' type='radio' class='iradio_minimal' value='" + i + "' name='msisdnSelected'/>" ;
html += "<label id='label" + i + "' for='numView" + dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn + "' class='ch-control'>";
html += dataPoolJSON[i].msisdn
html += "</label>";
```

Then your selector can be:

```
var row = $('#label'+selectedData[j].value).text();
```